# Setting PHP Include Path on a per site basis?

Tags: php, include

I can set the PHP include path in the `php.ini`:

```
include_path = /path/to/site/includes/
```

But then other websites are affected so that is no good.

I can set the PHP include in the start of every file:

```
$path = '/path/to/site/includes/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

But that seems like bad practice and clutters things up.

So I can make an include of that and then include it into every file:

```
include 'includes/config.php';
```

or

```
include '../includes/config.php';
```

This is what I'm doing right now, but the include path of `config.php` will change depending on what is including it.

Is there a better way? Does it matter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using apache as a webserver you can override (if you allow it) settings using *.htaccess* files. See [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/configuration.changes) for details.

Basically you put a file called *.htaccess* in your website root, which contains some PHP `ini` values. Provided you configured Apache to allow overrides, this site will use all values in your PHP config, + the values you specify in the *.htaccess* file.

> Can be used only with `PHP_INI_ALL` and `PHP_INI_PERDIR` type directives

as stated in the page I linked. If you click through to the full listing, you see that the include path is a `PHP_INI_ALL` directive.

Answer (score 7):

Erik Van Brakel gave, IMHO, one of the best answers.

More, if you're using Apache & Virtual hosts, you can set up includes directly in them. Using this method, you won't have to remember to leave php_admin commands in your .htaccess.

Answer (score 5):

Use a *php.ini* file in website *root*, if your setup uses *PHP* as *CGI* (the most frequent case on shared hosts) with the same syntax as the server-wide *php.ini*; put it into `.htaccess` if you have PHP as an Apache module (do a `phpinfo()` if unsure):

```
php_value include_path "wherever"
```

Note that per-folder `php.ini does` not affects *subfolders*.

Comment: `php_value include_path "/var/www/somesite.com/include_path/"`

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think append to include path is bad practice?

This code near top of root script shouldn't be that bad...

```
$path = '/path/to/site/includes/';
set_include_path($path . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

IMHO the main advantage is that it's portable and compatible not only with Apache

EDIT: I saw a drawback of this method: small performance impact. see http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html

Comment: Apart from the performance impact you mention, when I asked this question I was working on a site with many separate files and not a single root script which all requests are directed to.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your host is set up, you may be permitted to place a `php.ini` file in the root of your home directory with extra configuration directives.

Answer (score 1):

Your application should have a config file written in PHP. Then include that with a relative page into every page in the program. That config file will have a variable for the path to the includes dir, templates dir, images dir, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `include_path` in your php.ini file too. I'm a perl guy, so I expect to be able to load includes and have `include` do the right thing. I have all my includes in a specific directory, which is added to `include_path`. I can do things like

```
require_once "ClassName.php";
```

I don't need to worry about relative paths or locations of files.

I've also written my own `CustomRequire` to do things like

```
function CustomRequire ($file) {
    if(defined('MYINCLUDEPATH')) {
        require_once MYINCLUDEPATH . "/$file";
    } else {
        require_once $file;
    }
}
```

That way I can change how I do includes at a later date. Of course, you still need to find a way to include your include code :)

Comment: Why are people dissing @Gary's answer? A bad practice here at SO in my opinion - downvoting comments out of ones "limitless wisdom" *without* explaining it in the comments section.

Comment: Meh. That's PHP for you. I'm still using this system and it works great with APC performance wise. If you can, use an autoloader. The problem with an auto loader is you have to bastardize your class names if you want to have any sort of structure to your class layout on the file system (for example http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#49496). I'd love to hear better options!

Comment: Gary, i merely pointed out how people tend to downvote stuff without commenting on it. As far as I am concerned your answer is legitimate.