# Changing include path using php script

Tags: php

I'm looking to include other folders in my include path for PHP. I've seen this question:

[Setting PHP Include Path on a per site basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622/setting-php-include-path-on-a-per-site-basis)

**BUT** I don't want to replicate the system path (I suppose I could but then it won't update if the system path is updated). What I would rather is to simply have a line which looked like:

ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').$otherpaths);

Will this work, and is there some fundamental readon this is bad?

Comment: oo! A question by altCognito. How exciting. I thought you were only a man of answers. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this: [`set_include_path`](http://www.php.net/set_include_path)

With it, you can do:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $otherpath);
```

Comment: Hah, oh, for a while there, I'm slackin'. This qualifies as so simple why not ask? That's why it's here! Good to see you.