# Question related to 404 and PHP

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

So I'm using a single entry point found in a previous question of mine: [How to include config.php efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712973/how-to-include-config-php-efficiently/1713000#1713000)

We all know what 404 errors is, so no explanation needed there. However, when using the single entry point `index.php?page=pokemon`, it doesn't go to the 404 page when trying to access a page that is non-existent. So how can I solve this problem which would make it more user friendly and direct the visitors to my 404 page so they won't see all the PHP errors?

Comment: ... by showing a custom 404 page/error? `print "404 Page not found"; exit;` is the simplest way ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should output your own error page (you could just `include()` a .html file, for example), and set the HTTP status code using the `header()` function:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Of course, you must set the header before including the error template.

Comment: You do mean `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404);` don't you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do sort of an if / elseif or a switch on the variable $page to figure out which page to display, right?

If so, just add an ELSE resp. default: branch which will display a custom error note
to the user if an unexpected value is passed as $page.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you’re actually using [user187291’s code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712973/how-to-include-config-php-efficiently/1713000#1713000), alter it like this:

```
$page = "home";
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
$file = "$page.php";
if (preg_match('/\W/', $file) || !is_file($file)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    // print error message
    exit;
} else {
    include $file;
}
```

But since you’re using `header`, you need to make sure that no output has been sent to the client. Otherwise the HTTP header is already sent and you cannot modify it. You can use the [output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to buffer any output and discard it in case of an error.