# Working with paths - make a SITE_ROOT constant available on each page

Tags: php

I am a php newb and I am struggling with paths.

I have a config.php file in the root of my application where I have defined a constant which stores the parent's directory path.

```
define("SITE_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

The site will have different folders:
/includes/
/admin/
/theme/

Now, even if the SITE_ROOT constant is global, I understand that the global declaration is declared only until that script ends.

So for example, if I echo SITE_ROOT in admin.php, I will get a php error because I haven't included config.php into admin.php.

**Now, is there a way to skip including config.php in each and every file and make my SITE_ROOT constant available everywhere?**

TY very much! :)

Comment: I read this, look please at user Alex's response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712973/how-to-include-config-php-efficiently - who says "define it in the bootstrapping sequence of your application. Constants defined with define() are global." I dont have any idea on what bootstrapping means but since he has 121k points here he must know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a php ini setting [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), which lets you specify that a given file will be automatically loaded at the start of each request.

That being said, I would strongly recommend against using that approach.  If you can't `require_once("config.php")` at the top of each script, then an alternate approach is to use something like apache's mod_rewrite (via .htaccess) to route all requests to a single "bootstrap" script.  Include your `config.php` from there, then analyze the request, and load the appropriate script to handle it.

Comment: Ty for the answer, now I get what bootstrapping means. I guess I'll stick with including the config.php in every file.