# Including config.php "inside out", code explanation

Tags: php, regex, input, preg-replace, security

I was studying on how to include config.php efficiently in ever webpage of a website and I've found a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712973/how-to-include-config-php-efficiently) here on stackoverlow.

The user "user187291" gave a very interesting answer on how to include it, recommending an "inside out" approach.

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) 
   ? preg_replace("/\W+/", "", $_GET['page'])
   : "home";
 include "$page.php";
```

The question is, why does he uses preg_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` is being used to strip non alphanumeric characters from the `page` variable.

This is a very thin attempt at security. The code is attempting to prevent an injection attack.

Consider if the user requested the page http://www.example.com/index.php?page=/etc/passwd
Without sanitizing the input, the password file for the domain would happily be dumped to the screen.

The pattern `\W+` removes invalid characters such as the '/' character, preventing simple attacks such as this.

Comment: Ty for answering, this makes sense, do you think its the best security approach?

Comment: Security is a multi-layered discipline. There is no such thing as a silver bullet solution. However, best practice generally considers that multiple lines of defence are needed for security. So for example, sanitizing the user input in conjunction with checking if the file exists, checking if the file is in an allowable list of files etc.

Comment: Security is about managing risk, each layer of defence reduces the risk of penetration and makes it harder for an attacker to successfully compromise your system.

Comment: I am going to check your answer as the best one since you talked in depth about security and added some great points about checking if the page exists or is on an allowable list. How would you check if the page exists? btw

Comment: Thanks :). Checking file exists is possible with the file_exists function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Allowable list is more complicated. At the very least you might use an array of valid filenames and loop through to check if the value is in the array. Next step up would be a dictionary, after that you might consider storing the data in a text file for easy changing, next step up is a database.

Comment: I believe the code above is great because I can have a single page which includes all the scripts, and the code would load the templates for every needed page. So adding extra security means i'll be able to use it in a non testing enviroment

Answer (score 0):

The [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function takes the regular expression first parameter and replaces anything that matches with the second parameter in the third parameter.

I believe the author was doing this in an attempt to sanitize input from `$_GET`, whose values you shouldn't trust until you do.

For questions on web application security, I consult [The Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/), or OWASP. They have pages for [PHP Security Leading Practice](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Leading_Practice) as well as a [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Ty for answering, this makes sense, do you think its the best security approach?

Comment: Sanitizing your inputs as best as possible before using them is good security.  As @ose points out, it's not all you should do, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

\W detects all char that are not in [A-Za-z0-9_] (and delete it in the case of this replace) so it is to secure page parameter.