# Trying to use one include file on multiple subdirectories

Tags: php, include

I have a `header.php` that I'd like to include on all pages of the script I'm making. It has the nav bar and `header.php` includes `auth.php` which is some basic authentication you'd expect a header page to have.

The problem I am having is relative paths vs absolute paths. My directory structure looks like the below

```
/root
  -index.php (contains include ('inc/header.php');)
  -auth.php
  /inc
     -header.php (contains include ('auth.php);)
```

Now this works perfectly well. However when I add some functionality and get the following directory structure things start to break

```
/root
  -index.php (contains include ('inc/header.php');)
  -auth.php
  /inc
     -header.php (contains include ('auth.php);)
  /newFunctionality
     -newStuff.php (contains include('../inc/header.php') but breaks because of relative paths fidning auth.php
```

I've played around with things like `$fullPath = dirname(__FILE__);` and I believe that this is most likely how I'm going to fix this problem.

I've seen very similar questions with answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712973/how-to-include-config-php-efficiently). I'd like for this script to be independent of the index however. Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've alway found it easiest to set a base path constant and include my top level scripts base on that

```
  define ('APP_ROOT', '/path/to/application/root');
  include(APP_ROOT."/libs/MyFile.php");
```

Normally I would put this (along with any other site constants) in an include file and include it relative to the either the document root

```
  include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/config/site.php");
```

or specify the location of the file in my .htaccess

```
  SetEnv APP_CONFIG /path/to/application/config.php
```

then in php

```
  include ($_SERVER["APP_CONFIG"]);
```

Comment: those two lines would go in every file that is encountering this issue correct?

Comment: they would go in an include file that is included in each page, the include of that file can be based on either the document root i.e. `include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/config.php";` or if you don't like using the document root you can put a SetEnv Line in your htaccess file `SetEnv APP_CONFIG /path/to/config.file;` then in php `include ($_SERVER["APP_CONFIG"]);`

Comment: i was able to retrofit all my includes to work perfectly. I attempted to also do this for the `href`'s but it doesn't seem like IIS likes that. Am I being dumb thinking I should do it to those too?