# Defining PHP constants in header file doesnt work?

Tags: php, constants

I tried to define constants in my config.php file. Its primary use is just configuration, as I'm sure you guessed. But it isn't working. here's my config.php file:

```
<?php
    define("KPEREQUEST", "0", true);
    define("KPERESPONSE", "1", true);

    define("KPEGET", 0, true);
    define("KPEPOST", 1, true);
?>
```

and here's the result when I include config.php and print the define kPAPost:

```
KPEPOST: ""
```

but here's the result if i define the constants in index.php AND i print them from index.php:

```
KPEPOST: "1"
```

**** EDIT ****

heres my index.php file:

```
<?php
    $title = "API Documents";
    include 'header.php';
    include "config.inc.php";

    echo "KPEPOST: \"" . KPEPOST . "\""; 
?>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I've seen this done a million times in wordpress, magento, etc. I have no idea why this isn't working and I've done a ton of research to figure it out but I'm at a dead end now. Any help would be appreciated. Why can't I define a constant in a config file and use the define in files that include the config file?

Comment: printing the define:
    include "config.inc.php";

    echo "KPEPOST: \"" . KPEPOST . "\"";

Comment: Please show the actual code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: `kPAPost` is not defined did you mean `KPEPOST`

Comment: right thats what i meant. i showed the files though. thats a direct copy and paste

Comment: Please enable full error_reporting, and see what that says; and also use `require` instead of `include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just don't have **config.php** (or that particular copy of config.php) in your include path.

#### Suggestion

1. Define a root **index.php** for your entire web app;
2. Do this:

   ```
   define('BASE_DIR', realpath(__FILE__));
   ```
3. Then you can do this:

   ```
   require_once BASE_DIR.'config.php';
   ```

#### Further reading

- [How to include config.php efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712973/how-to-include-config-php-efficiently)
- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: although i used dirname() instead of realpath()

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution is to use ./ in front of the filename during the include. i discovered it inadvertently.

```
define("kPEPost", "1");
```

and the include:

```
include("./header");
include("./includes/config.inc.php");
```