# Is using one copy of a framework a bad idea?

Tags: php, frameworks

Currently, I'm working with a company that has several different projects, all running on an older copy of a PHP framework. That PHP framework is installed in a shared directory on the server, and added to PHP's include path, so that typing `require 'Framework/Lib.php` or whatever will load Lib.php from the shared directory. None of the projects have their own copy of the framework.

I see this as a pretty bad idea, but I'm not really sure why (Other than the main point of not being able to update the framework, so we're stuck using an old version).

Are there any other negative side effects to this, or is it not as bad as I think?

Comment: One point would be that you aren't able to fix some bugs on which other projects rely.

Comment: If the framework allows this, and you're not going to touch it, it doesn't sound like such a terrible idea. Especially if you archive copies by version, so you can upgrade on a per-project basis (symlinks may work well here)

Comment: i like wholly self-contained 'projects' but then it sucks when i have a bug and have to fix it 10 times - there are allways pros\cons

Comment: If you're using Apache, you could perfectly combine @Pekka웃's idea and a per-directory PHP include path. So you won't have to worry about versions in your code, rather in one *.htaccess* file. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622/setting-php-include-path-on-a-per-site-basis

Comment: This is not a bad idea per say, but it all depends how well the framework component is managed. If arbitrary changes are made without consideration of the wider impact, you are going to find yourself in a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem, nor unusual.

If you need to have multiple copies of a library or framework, you can set the PHP include path as required for each project individually in its own php.ini or htaccess file.

This means you can keep working the way you are, but use whichever library version you want for any given project.

The added advantage is that if you need to upgrade one of your projects, you can change the library version of that project simply by altering the include path in the htaccess file, without needing to install any extra copies of the library or affect any other projects.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem may be if you are going to modify the framework codebase, because you may never know what application may break if you patch the framework.

But: if you are doing unit tests on every application that depends on the framework, then you can launch tests and check if there's any failure and eventually revert to the previous situation, or fix the test failures with enough confidence.

If you are not doing automated testing or can't modify app codebase then it may be an issue (I repeat, only if you need to modify the framework code).

I can't see any other issues deriving from that, it may even be a (small and debatable) advantage (so that everybody is using the same version of the framework).

And since it's old stuff, there's no need to worry about Composer dependency management, I don't think you are using it, am I right?